# What is the difference between Data Extension and Salesforce Data Extension in salesforce marketing cloud (exacttarget)?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

The Documentation says that Salesforce Data extension is visible if the "Enhanced Subscriber features" is turned On. But it does not say what is "Enhanced Subscriber feature". What are the pros and cons of using both the data extensions?

[image]

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Salesforce Data Extension is used only when you are Integrating with a Salesforce Org. You can pull data from a Salesforce object (Using Import Activity) and store in a Salesforce DE.

You cannot create a Salesforce DE just like you create a standard DE. To use a Salesforce DE, you'll have to copy its data to a standard DE using a Query Activity.
Hope it helps .

Comment: One additional comment, is that it doesn't really make a difference in the system whether or not the DE is a salesforce data extension or not. What's important is the folder in which the data extension is stored (for tracking purposes)

Answer (score 0):

A salesforce Data Extension used when we fetch data from the sales cloud through cloud connect. They are contacts or lead which will be imported form SFDE. if we create Salesforce Data Extension As a Standard Data Ext then we have to add these record as a subscriber.

You can Create Salesforce Data Extension As a standard data Extension but after entered all record you need to update this record as a subscriber before sending any campaign.

Also, we have different folders for data Ext. and Salesforce Data Ext.