# Salesforce Data Extensions help

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, email-tracking

If we don't have Sales & Service Cloud in our stack, is there still a case for using Salesforce Data Extensions over standard Data Extensions? I have read that by using Salesforce Data Extensions the tracking is sent back to Sales Cloud, but if we don't have this, is there any benefit?

Any insight is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Maybe this topic can help: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/164050/what-is-the-difference-between-data-extension-and-salesforce-data-extension-in-s

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, you don't need [Salesforce Data Extensions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_salesforce_data_extensions.htm&type=5) if the Marketing Cloud account is not related/connected to Sales or Service.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for your help :)